# Троеточие в multi-select

Tags: html, css, reactjs, select

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать троеточие в multi-select (библиотека: react-select), что бы туда прятать те опции, которые не помещаются в длину селекта, что бы они не переносились на новую строку. Не знаю как к этой библиотеке применить text-overflow: ellipsis.

`import Select from 'react-select'

function Selector ({label,  onInput, value, multiple, options}) {

return

```
  <Select options={options} onChange={onInput} isMulti={multiple} value={value} controlShouldRenderValue={true}/>  
</div>
```

}

Selector.defaultProps = {
label: '',
options: [],
multiple: false,
// value:''
}

export default Selector`

Comment: Добавьте сюда HTML вашего текущего результата вывода мультиселекта вместе c CSS отвечающего за этот блок.

Comment: @stylok Добавил компонент в котором создан этот селект, а весь css он от самой библиотеки (react-select), или про какой css, вы говорили, подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

А-а, так вы о этих "селектах". Да ещё и выпадающем. Дабы вы знали на будущее... практически все формы стилизуются весьма плохо. Это так сказать "наследие" от операционных систем ведущее к браузеру, где каждый со своими дефалтными тараканами, а дальше: "вы, дизайнеры, должны страдать".)

Раньше было ещё хуже. Однако, с годами ситуация потихоньку улучшалась, и, хотя ещё далека от совершенства, но всё же меняется.

Вернёмся к вашему элементу. Но приведу его на двух примерах одновременно.

```css
select {
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

option {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<select name="multi" size="2" >
  <option value="very-long">Очень длинный текст скрываемый за многоточием</option>
  <option value="long" disabled="">Здесь текст не такой длинный</option>
</select>

<select name="open">
  <option value="very-long">Очень длинный текст скрываемый за многоточием</option>
  <option value="long" disabled="">Здесь текст не такой длинный</option>
</select>
```

P.S. есть сторонние библиотеки элементов форм. Появился `Shadow DOM`, позволяющий написать эти формы самому на свой вкус. Но, если для вас ситуация с сокращением текста критична, а изучать и копаться в этом не хочется то можно исправить и обычным сокращением текста при помощи js. Если кратко и по смыслу, а не по полному действию то как-то так:

```
let long = "Очень длинный текст скрываемый за многоточием";
let short = long.slice(0,19) + '...';
console.log(short);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное вам за помощь. Мой уровень не позволяет адаптировать это решение именно на react-select, но я тогда просто заменю пока что на обычный селект, как здесь представлено, если я все правильно понял.